# Should classes be final by default?

Tags: c++

Quoting the Effective C++ (Scott Meyers), third edition, item 7:

> Declare destructors virtual in polymorphic base classes.

This implies that classes intended to be inherited from should, at a minimum, have the destructor virtual.

When writing some applications/libraries, some classes (I would say not few) are not designed with the intention of being inherited from. We usually rely on some conventions, in which one is not supposed to inherit classes that are not his own or without checking if it's safe to.

Now, a coding standard may require to write and design classes such that inheritance is always safe. I feel like this might be too much. C++11 has added the `final` keyword that makes sure classes are not inherited from. Would you recommend marking all classes that are not designed for inheritance as `final` by default?

This would make the compiler enforce what we have been doing by convention for ages. But that convention might be considered well enough understood and easy to follow (especially since inheritance is usually avoided, with composition being preferred) such that it might be just another thing to care of while writing the code.

Comment: I do not agree with 'inheritance is usually avoided'. Also, non-polymorphic inheritance plays an important role in template metaprogramming context.

Comment: *"Would you recommend marking all classes that are not designed for inheritance as final by default?"* - well, that is what `final` is for. At the same time declaring destructors virtual only makes sense if you want to support keeping ownership of object through a pointer to base class, which is often not in case

Comment: @SergeyA Indeed, inheritance is widely used. I was referring that composition is usually preferred, and it's usually avoided from classes that are not yours (e.g. from the classes of a library).

Comment: @VTT You are right, but I cannot be sure how the users are going to use the class. Shouldn't the class be robust to all use cases?

Comment: That probably depends on context. Typically when class is internal (not part of public interface that is) I tend to make use of it as restricted as possible. This often allows to gain performance benefits by making such class more "specialized" for particular use cases. The common example are classes designed to be used with intrusive containers.

Comment: "avoided with classes that are not yours" - even that is not accurate. I routinely inherit from `std::integral_constant`.

Answer (score 5):

Just because a class does not have any virtual functions does *not* mean that inheriting from it does not make sense. It just means it was probably not intended and that you have to be careful not to delete any instances of the derived objects through pointers to the base class. `private` inheritance would *often* be used in such a case, as an alternative to composition, to signal that inheriting from the base is purely an implementation detail and the derived class is not to be considered as having a "is-a" relationship with the base.

Marking a class `final` is a great way to express that a class is not intended to be derived from, at all, by making it impossible. So if that's what you want, slap a `final` on the class.

In some cases, marking a (derived) class `final` to prevent any *further* derivatives can also have the added benefit of making it easier for the compiler to devirtualize function calls, thus leading to better performance in some cases.

In *my* opinion, `final` should (usually) be the default and you can then remove it later if you find that you need/want to derive from the class after all. 
But that's just opinion.

Comment: I've been using `final` a lot, and it has helped to signal that a class that one NOW wants to inherit from needs some clean-up work done to make it properly inheritable.  Especially for large projects (mine has 30,000,000 lines of code).  But as with many things in C++, it's a convention that the modern C++ supports.  Not all teams would be happy with that convention -- talk to your team mates, and come to an agreement.

Comment: @Eljay: For me it feels that `final` means: Something is wrong with me ( the class ) so that is technical not possible to derive from me. I see only rare cases where to use `final`.

Comment: closed source libraries( commercial OS APIs ...) can mark their classes as final - to make some separations from user code. The keyword just means ' for composition only ' and is good in libraries that also try PIMPL.